# Shipping python runtime with excel

Tags: python, xlwings

According to the xlwings website:-

Easy deployment: The receiver of an xlwings-powered spreadsheets only needs Python with minimal dependencies — or nothing at all when shipped with the Python runtime.

I have installed Anaconda and written some python code and run it from Excel using xlwings

I put this spreadsheet on a different computer than the one I developed on and placed the python.exe and a few dll's that got installed with Anaconda into a directory with the spreadsheet

I added the path to the environment variables so it could find python

The spreadsheet looked like it invoked python but got an overflow error

I'm trying to ship the spreadsheet in the leanest possible manner.  I don't really want to have to get all users to install python

Is this approach possible and which files do I need to include?

Answer (score 0):

"When shipped with the Python runtime" is referring to the underdocumented approach of using a freezer (like py2exe or cx_Freeze) and creating a self-contained directory that includes the whole Python dependency.

There is the standalone version of the [Fibonacci example](https://github.com/ZoomerAnalytics/xlwings/tree/master/examples/fibonacci) where you can see how it is being done. You can also download the respective "standalone" sample from http://www.xlwings.org/examples.